# Direct Link to React Netlify Function app Showing as Not Found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, server-side-rendering, netlify

I am building a React - Netlify Function App. The app is using react-router-dom to route to pages.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Switch,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  withRouter,
  browserHistory
} from 'react-router-dom';
...
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <IdentityContextProvider url={url}>
    <Page>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={withTracker(HomePage)} />
        <Route exact path="/demo" component={withTracker(Demo)} />
```

However, when users type the URL directly into the browser address bar to go to the link then it shows as not found. Does that mean I also need Server-side rendering? What is the quickest way to add Server-Side Rendering to the existing app?

We plan to point different Ads to different page links of the website.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you need to create a _redirects file , it's a file that tells Netlify where it should redirect the clients based on the address or route that they are attempting to request.

1- Create a file named _redirects inside of your public folder, there is no file extension.

2- The code for the file :

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

3-Rebuild and deploy your project.

Read this article to help you more : https://www.edwardbeazer.com/routing-react-apps-hosted-on-netlify/

Comment: What if i dont have a public folder but the Frontend code is inside the app folder.
Added a new public folder as well as add the file inside the /app folder where the index.html file is and still not working

Comment: OK Figure out the BUILD or PUBLIC folder ( The react Compiled folder)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a DemoPage component and point react router to said page and then have it load withTracker(Demo) and add more logic after page it self load.